# FlatList inside ScrollView in React-Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm learning to use react-native by creating an application, so I'm creating a scrollable homepage and inside it 10 rectangle with different names. If I understand correctly, you need to use flatlist to manage the scrolling of these rectangles, but I already have a scrollview within the same page. I have something like this:

```
<ScrollView> 
  <Image/>
  <Text/>
  <RectangleComponents/>
</ScrollView>
```

Inside RectanglesComponent is the code that creates the 10 rectangles. I'm currently using a ScrollView here too because I couldn't use FlatList inside a ScrollView. Example of RectanglesComponent:

```
    return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        {Array.from(Array(10).keys()).map(i => ( 
            <SafeAreaView key={i} style={styles.rectangle}/>
    </SafeAreaView>
    );
```

In this case i need to use FlatList or ScrollView is good?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<ScrollView nestedScrollEnabled = {true}>
 ......
  <ScrollView nestedScrollEnabled = {true}>
    .....
  </ScrollView>
</ScrollView>
```

Note: RN should be greater then 56.0

Example:
https://snack.expo.dev/@msbot01/blessed-orange-yogurt

```
import {View, Text, SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, ScrollView, Image } from 'react-native';

// You can import supported modules from npm
import { Card } from 'react-native-paper';

// or any files within the Snack
import AssetExample from './components/AssetExample';

export default function App() {

  const rectBox=()=>{
    var tempArray = [];

    for(var i=0; i<10;i++){
      let eachElement = <View style={{height:150,width:'100%',backgroundColor:'green', marginTop:20}}>
          <Text>{i}</Text>
      </View>
      tempArray.push(eachElement)
    }

    return tempArray;
  }

  const rectBox02=()=>{
    var tempArray = [];

    for(var i=0; i<10;i++){
      let eachElement = <View style={{height:150,width:'100%',backgroundColor:'yellow', marginTop:20}}>
          <Text>{i}</Text>
      </View>
      tempArray.push(eachElement)
    }

    return tempArray;
  }

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
     <ScrollView nestedScrollEnabled = {true}>
        <Image
        style={styles.tinyLogo}
        source={{
          uri: 'https://reactnative.dev/img/tiny_logo.png',
        }}
      />
      
      <ScrollView nestedScrollEnabled = {true} style={{height:300}}>
        {rectBox()}
      </ScrollView>

      <ScrollView nestedScrollEnabled = {true} style={{height:300}}>
        {rectBox02()}
      </ScrollView>

     </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  tinyLogo: {
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
  }
});
```